# Initial Zoom when rendering XML in VS2013 too high

Tags: visual-studio-2013, settings

When viewing the field.OuterXml in the XML Visualizer the initial zoom level is set very high. When testing the application from VS other instances of increased zoom levels in other locations where XML is rendered. Interestingly, only this particular piece seems to be affected, the zoom for everything else is normal.

I've been looking for a setting that might affect this, but haven't managed to find anything that would let me set it. CTRL+Scroll works to adjust it as expected.

Any suggestions?  I haven't been able to locate anything that seemed relevent or any other people with this problem. I even tried Bing thinking it might give me more useful results when asking about VS.

[image: XML Visualizer Zoom]

I have tried the following

- Zoom out from IE - This didn't have an effect, IE defaults to 100% zoom when opened.

Comment: Try zooming out in IE.

Comment: IE currently defaults to 100% zoom when opened. Adjusting the zoom in IE doesn't seem to affect the zoom levels of this item. I'll give a shot at resetting the settings in IE a little later on to see if that helps any.